# Can we get the product of two gamma matrices in Quantum Mechanics to yield the matrix with i on the diagonal and zero elsewhere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-matrices

Can we get the product of two gamma matrices in Quantum Mechanics to yield the matrix with i on the diagonal and zero elsewhere? There can be different basis for the gamma matrices. I wonder if a particular basis will give us this property. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to explain something about the motivation for the question.

Comment: The answer is no. The result would be hermitian, and the diagonal of a hermitian matrix has to have real values - since real values are their complex conjugate.

Comment: But on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices, it says that Gamma (0) is the time-like, hermitian matrix. The other three are space-like, anti-hermitian matrices. I am interested in the other three matrices, Gamma 1 to 3, not Gamma (0). That is, I wonder if the product of any two of the three will yield i on the diagonal and zero elsewhere. If Gamma 1 to 3 are anti-hermitian, I guess the product of any two of them will be anti-hermitian and so the diagonal has to be imaginary, not real. In that case, it seems that what I am looking for is possible. Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: If this is homework, please reference the source, add the homework-and-exercises tag, and follow our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: This is not homework. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: The anticommutator of two antihermitean matrices is hermitean, and the commutator antihermitean (but always traceless, much unlike the identity!).

Answer (score 2):

No. Use representation-independent properties, 
$$
\{ \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \} = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu = 2 \eta^{\mu \nu} I_4
$$
and 
$$
\operatorname {Tr} ~ [ \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu ] = 0.
$$
But 
$$
  \gamma^\mu  \gamma^\nu =  \{ \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \}/ 2 +  [\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu ]/2 ,
 $$
so the commutator must contain the imaginary piece times the identity, and thus not be traceless: impossible by above.

Comment: I’m confused. The OP’s desired product isn’t traceless.

Comment: @G.Smith. That's the point. If the anticommutator is real and proportional to the identity, the commutator must be complex and proportional to the identity, which it cannot be, since traceless.